# Format of JSON received at node/express server

Tags: ajax, json, node.js, express

I am sending data from the client to the server.

```
// client
var messageObj = {};
messageObj.fromUserId = 1;
messageObj.messageContent = "print this";
$.ajax({
    url: "/sendMessage",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(messageObj)
})


// server
app.post('/sendMessage', function (req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.body);
        return res.status(200);
    });
```

Why is the `console.log` output, this:

```
{ '{"fromUserId":1,"messageContent":"print this"}': '' }
```

and not this ? (and how can I get it to this ?)

```
{"fromUserId":1,"messageContent":"print this"}
```

Comment: okay, if simply send `data: messageObj`, I get the desired output. But isn't it preferable to send JSON instead of native javascript objects ?

Comment: Is it? Also you're not sending `native javascript objects`, they are serialized into key=value pairs. If you want to send json try setting the content type header. `contentType: 'application/json',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default, unless you specify something else, is to send the data URI-encoded and to tell the server that's how it's being sent. If you're going to send JSON, you need to tell both the browser (and jQuery) and the server that by specifying `contentType`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/sendMessage",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(messageObj)
})
```